# C++ : how to know if a point I intersects two line segments?

Tags: c++

I have two line segments given by their equations  `A1x + B1y + C1 = 0` and `A2x + B2y + C2 = 0`, the coordinates of the intersection point `I` of these two line segments can be computed as follows:

```
x1 =B2*C1 − B1*C2 / A2*B1 − A1*B2

y1 =A1*C2 − A2*C1 / A2*B1 − A1*B2
```

I'm working with double values, how to know if `I=(x1,y1)` intersects the two line segments?

I tried replacing the values of `x1` and `y1` in the equations of the line segments but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" is not a useful description of the problem.

Comment: Those are equations of lines not line segments?

Comment: You set the two equations equal to one another by setting them both to zero. Now you have two equations and two uknowns. Solving them will give the x, y value where the lines intersect (or there will be no solution if the lines do not.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need brackets:

```
x1 = (B2*C1 − B1*C2) / (A2*B1 − A1*B2);
y1 = (A1*C2 − A2*C1) / (A2*B1 − A1*B2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be the calculation of 2 constants for both lines (the angle tangent and offset) and checking intersection with them

```
(L1) y1 = k1 * x1 + b1
(L2) y2 = k2 * x2 + b2

// where

k1 = A1 / B1 and b1 = C1 / B1
k2 = A2 / B2 and b2 = C2 / B2 

// If they intersect (y1 == y2) and (x1 == x2)
// Subtract them and you will get
0 == (k1 - k2) * x + (b1 - b2)
x = (b2 - b1) / (k1 - k2)
// After getting the x
y = k1 * x + b1 or y = k2 * x + b2
```

To check, whether they intersect or not you can check `if (k1 == k2)`
To check, whether they are perpendicular, you can check `if (k1 * k2 == -1)`